# how to call javascript method in a javacode

Tags: java, javascript

i'm trying to call a javascript method in a java code but i get many errors , so i put the method in the main to check it so i get this in the console   "sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction"
 and I don't see a way to invoke it.
thanks

```
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception
  {
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();

    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
    String myJSCode = "function calcul()"
            + "{"
            + "alert('Veuillez verifier le nom et le prenom saisis ');"
            + "}";
    System.out.println(engine.eval(myJSCode));

  }
```

Comment: How would an `alert` work without a GUI?

Comment: i'm a beginner and i need your help please

Answer (score 1):

The `alert()` method is not part of the core Javascript language. It is only present when a script is running in a web browser. As such, it is not available in a Javascript `ScriptEngine` instance. (And no, using `ScriptEngine` in a Java applet doesn't count. That just gets really confusing and I wouldn't recommend it at all.)

If you want to test displaying something to the console, try calling `print()` instead. I believe this function is part of the Rhino runtime.

Comment: still have the same problen even i change alert by print 
"sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction@12e9d91"

Answer (score 1):

i tried this and it worked:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();  
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");  


        // JavaScript code in a String  
        String script = "function Msg() {print('Veuillez verifier le nom et le prenom saisis !!! '); }";  
        // evaluate script  
        engine.eval(script);  

        // javax.script.Invocable is an optional interface.  
        // Check whether your script engine implements or not!  
        // Note that the JavaScript engine implements Invocable interface.  
        Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;  

        // invoke the global function named "hello"  
        inv.invokeFunction("Msg" );  


    } `
```

now i want to do some changes :

1) **change the print to a Message box**

2) **put the whole code into a method that it will be called in the html code 
   and like this the message box will be showed to the user in the screen**

thanks a lot for your help .

Answer (score 0):

The message was actually it telling you that it evaluated (it would complain if you had called the function you defined though).  Here is an example with print that output:

```
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception
{
  ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();

  ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
  String myJSCode = "function calcul()"
                  + "{"
                  +   "print ('Veuillez verifier le nom et le prenom saisis ');"
                  + "}"
                  + "\n"
                  + "calcul();";
  engine.eval(myJSCode);
}
```

This outputs:

```
Veuillez verifier le nom et le prenom saisis
```

Or if you are just calling a function to return it's output you can use a self executing anonymous function like this:

```
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception
{
  ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();

  ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
  String myJSCode = "(function()"
                  + "{"
                  +   "return 'Veuillez verifier le nom et le prenom saisis';"
                  + "})()";
  System.out.println(engine.eval(myJSCode));
}
```

This returns the same thing

Comment: the `print()` in the JavaScript will output, the `System.out.println()` isn't needed

Comment: still have the same error   "sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction@1aed7c1"

Comment: `InterpretedFunction` is not an error (though it does look like one).  It is the return type is evaluated JavaScript that is interpreted as a function.  You can call this function by following this more complex example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3981418/16959

Comment: still have this ""sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction"

Answer (score 0):

The other issue with your code is that it's just defining a function called `calcul` but it's not invoking it.  Building off what @duskwuff said and removing the alert, you could define and invoke the function as follows:

```
  String myJSCode = "function calcul()"
        + "{"
        + "println('hello world');"
        + "return true;"
        + "}" +
        "calcul();";
```